# Meteor deployment runs no node-gyp rebuild

Tags: meteor, deployment, npm, node-gyp

When deploying my bundle on the server (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), there is no node-gyp rebuild for my bcrypt package.

**Step 1**

When running in `/bundle/programs/server/` the `npm install` command, I just get the following output:

```
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
\
> fibers@1.0.15 install /path/to/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-46` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/var/www/vhosts/caroapp.de/curriculum.caroapp.de/app/bundle/programs/server)
ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

duplexer2@0.1.4 node_modules/duplexer2

object-assign@4.1.1 node_modules/object-assign

inherits@2.0.3 node_modules/inherits

amdefine@1.0.1 node_modules/amdefine

supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

string_decoder@1.0.3 node_modules/string_decoder

strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

process-nextick-args@1.0.7 node_modules/process-nextick-args

util-deprecate@1.0.2 node_modules/util-deprecate

through2@2.0.3 node_modules/through2

core-util-is@1.0.2 node_modules/core-util-is

safe-buffer@5.1.1 node_modules/safe-buffer

isarray@1.0.0 node_modules/isarray

semver@5.3.0 node_modules/semver

multipipe@1.0.2 node_modules/multipipe

split2@2.1.1 node_modules/split2

asap@2.0.6 node_modules/asap

xtend@4.0.1 node_modules/xtend

meteor-promise@0.8.5 node_modules/meteor-promise

source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

readable-stream@2.3.3 node_modules/readable-stream

source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

promise@8.0.1 node_modules/promise

fibers@1.0.15 node_modules/fibers
... installation complete
```

This was already strange, because usually there is a node-gyp rebuild for the bcrypt!? (It must run here, too, otherwise it would use the local build, that could potentially build towards another kernel, deps versions etc.)

**Step 2**

Then on startup, there is still the message, that I am running on the JS implementation of bcrypt.

**Step 3**

Next step was doing an `npm list` in the server dir, which returned:

```
meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 /path/to/bundle/programs/server
├── amdefine@1.0.1
├── ansi-regex@0.2.1
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── asap@2.0.6
├── chalk@0.5.1
├── core-util-is@1.0.2
├── duplexer2@0.1.4
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
├── fibers@1.0.15
├── has-ansi@0.1.0
├── inherits@2.0.3
├── isarray@1.0.0
├── meteor-promise@0.8.5
├── multipipe@1.0.2
├── **UNMET DEPENDENCY node-gyp@3.6.0**
├── **UNMET DEPENDENCY node-pre-gyp@0.6.34**
├── object-assign@4.1.1
├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
├── promise@8.0.1
├── readable-stream@2.3.3
├── safe-buffer@5.1.1
├── semver@5.3.0
├── source-map@0.1.32
├── source-map-support@0.3.2
├── split2@2.1.1
├── string_decoder@1.0.3
├── strip-ansi@0.3.0
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── through2@2.0.3
├── underscore@1.5.2
├── util-deprecate@1.0.2
└── xtend@4.0.1
```

**Step 4**

`node-gyp`and `node-pre-gyp` were globally installed via:

```
npm install npde-gyp@3.6.0 -g
npm install node-pre-gyp@0.6.34 -g
```

Which installed them as global packages without an error, **BUT** when deleting the bundle folder and reproducing the steps above, I still get the same result.

I am totally in the dark here. Someone has a clue?

---

Edit:

**dev -> package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "i-wont-build",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha",
    "test-watch": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test-chrome": "TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha",
    "test-phantom": "TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=phantomjs meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha",
    "test-nightmare": "TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=nightmare meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha",
    "test-watch-nightmare": "TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=nightmare TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --driver-package dispatch:mocha",
    "test-chimp": "chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --watch --mocha --path=tests",
    "test-full": "meteor test --full-app --driver-package tmeasday:acceptance-test-driver"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "awesomplete": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bpmn-js": "^0.20.6",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.13.1",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.8",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "get-project-version": "^1.0.3",
    "ghissues": "^1.1.3",
    "github-create-issue": "^2.0.0",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "html5sortable": "^0.4.5",
    "ids": "^0.2.0",
    "indexof": "0.0.1",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "matches-selector": "^1.0.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.6",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.17",
    "min-dom": "^0.2.0",
    "mmmagick": "^0.4.5",
    "node-emoji": "^1.5.1",
    "object-refs": "^0.2.0",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.2.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.28.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "nightmare": "^2.10.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.47.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you also show your `package.json`?

Comment: thx, I attached the contents to the post,

Comment: Just 2 questions to clarify: 1) Did you run `meteor npm i` _before_ building meteor bundle? 2) Are you running `npm i` on your `Ubuntu` server as usual user or as `root`?

Comment: 1 - yes - 2 - root - edit real root, no sudo

Comment: Ah, #2 is your problem. Have a look at this comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7773#issuecomment-261088681

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: Great, working with `--unsafe-perm` (requirements were met already). You can make this an answer if you want, since it solved my problem.